# Stack allocation of object with virtual function leads to unexpeted behavior (calls base class method instead of child class)

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I have a basic class which is getting inherited by inherited class player.

```
class Entity{
   public:
    virtual std::string getName(){ return "Hello World";}
 };
```

In my extended class I am just trying to override getName method like following snippet:

```
  class Player : public Entity{
    public:
    std::string getName() override { return "Hello from Player"; }
  };
```

When I allocate the object on heap it calls the right extended class method, I get output "Hello from Player" allocation object on heap is done like:

```
Entity* e= new Entity;
  Player* p = new Player;
  Entity* entity = p;
  std::cout << entity->getName() <<std::endl;
```

But when I allocate the same object on stack, it calls the base method instead of overridden method, I have done stack allocation as:

```
Entity e1;
  Player p1;
  Entity entity1 = p1;
  std::cout << entity1.getName() <<std::endl;
```

The combined output of the whole code looks like:

> Hello from Player
>   -------------- Hello World

I am using clang version 7.0.0-3~ubuntu0.18.04.1 with **c++11** flag, was hoping if can any one explain to me this behavior. Isn't stack or heap allocation suppose to have no effect on how object behaves? or am I missing something? 
I have tried to google the topic without getting any accurate relevant answers.
Here is a repl.it link: https://repl.it/repls/GleefulDroopyRay

Comment: Polymorphism is C++ works only with pointers and references.

Comment: @Gils Just like in other languages, though those often don't allow value-semantics at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called **slicing**.

When you do:

```
Entity entity1 = p1;
```

You call the copy constructor of class Entity and create an actual Entity object which is the base. Thus the method of the base is called.

If you want to have an example with objects on the stack you could do one of the following:

```
Player p1;
Entity& entity1 = p1;
std::cout << entity1.getName() <<std::endl;
```

Or

```
Player p1;
Entity* pEntity = &p1;
std::cout << pEntity->getName() <<std::endl;
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, and thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I was able to understand the concept from videos on 'slicing', on why this behavior occurs!